# Dictionary containing List

Tags: c#, dictionary

The below code:

```
public struct Value
{
    List<string> RFcode;
    int found;
    int expected;
    public int Found { get { return found; } }
    public int Expected { get { return expected; } }
    public List<string> Code { get { return RFcode; } }
    public Value(int f, int exp, string s)
    {
        this.found = f;
        this.expected = exp;
        RFcode.Add(s);
    }
}
```

is Invalid. On VS debug  I get :

```
Error   1   Field 'BE_EOR.InvCyclic.Value.RFcode' must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller

Error   2   Use of possibly unassigned field 'RFcode'
```

Comment: Pretty self explanatory, you never set `RFCode` (What does this question have to do with a dictionary?)

Comment: A struct with a List in it? Cries "Class" for me

Comment: You need to instantiated the RFcode variable before being used in constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this one:

```
List<string> RFcode = new List<string>();
```

The reason, why you get this error is the fact, that you haven't created a list, which will hold the strings you want. However, you try to add elements in this list:

```
RFcode.Add(s);
```

This line of code, `List<string> RFcode;`, it justs defines a variable called `RFcode`, that will keep a reference to a List of strings. Neither it creates a list nor it assings it to this variable.

**Update**

As already Christian Sauer has pointed out and Kensei have reminded it to us, it would be better you use a class rather than the struct you use:

```
public class Value
{
    public List<string> RFCode { get; set; }
    public int Found { get; set; }
    public int Expected { get; set; }

    public Value(string s, int found, int expected)
    {
        RFCode = new List<string> { s }; 
        Found = found;
        Expected = expected;
    }
}
```

However, at this point I have to raise a question. Why are you using a List of strings, since you only pass a string to your constructor? If that's the case, to pass only a string, I don't think that's a good design, since you don't use the most appropriate type for that you want.

Comment: There it goes your answer, but please... use a Class as @Christian Sauer told you...

Comment: My problem is that RFCode = new List<string> { s };  creates every time a new List with element s, and doesn't add new elements

Comment: A list will be created only the first time you create an object of tyoe `Value`. Then you could add values to this list as times as you want.